# How to the display the number of instances of a string in vim statusline

Tags: function, vim, statusline

A while ago I got to find a function to use in .vimrc to show if there ocurrances of `" TODO "` in the current buffer and show **TD** in the statusline. This is the function:

```
...
hi If_TODO_COLOR ctermbg=0 ctermfg=175 cterm=bold
set statusline+=%#If_TODO_COLOR#%{If_TODO()}
...

function! If_TODO()
    let todos = join(getline(1, '$'), "\n")
    if todos =~? " TODO "
        return " TD "
    else
        return ""
    endif
endfunction
```

My question is how can I modify the function to also return how many times the string has appeared in the buffer - somthing like **TD (6)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `:help filter()` the lines to get a list of lines containing `TODO`:

```
let lines = getline(1, '$')
let todos = filter(lines, 'v:val =~? " TODO "')
return len(todos) > 0 ? 'TD' : ''
```

The same thing, expressed in a slightly more "modern" way:

```
return getline(1, '$')
    \ ->filter('v:val =~? " TODO "')
    \ ->len() > 0 ? 'TD' : ''
```

See `:help method`.

Comment: The first one works well. Exactly what i wanted. Thanks.